# What is the $k$th differential of a composite map?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $V$, $W$, and $X$ be normed linear spaces, and let $A$ be an open subset of $V$. Suppose $F \in C^k(A,W)$ and $G \in C^k(W,X)$. What is $d^k(G\circ F)_\alpha$ (the $k$th differential of $G \circ F$ at $\alpha \in A$)?

For $k=1$, $$d(G\circ F)_\alpha = dG_{F(\alpha)} \circ dF_\alpha.$$

What is the general formula?

Comment: Just use the product rule and chain rule repeatedly. It's not particularly clean.

Comment: @aes Where is the product rule used?

Comment: The $\circ$ on the RHS is a composition of linear maps, and satisfies the product rule (in coordinates it would be a matrix product). As a first go, do the single variable case, which is actually completely analogous.

Comment: @aes I'd appreciate it if you would explain everything in detail in an answer (without using coordinates). My book mentioned this in passing, and I want to see how it's done.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula

Answer (score 1):

**I'll do the second derivative without using coordinates**

*Here's an explanation of the product rule part of this*:

What is $dF_\alpha$? For each $\alpha \in A$, it's a linear map from $V \rightarrow W$. So really $dF_-: A \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$. Its derivative at $\alpha$ is a linear map from $V \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(V,W)$ (which is equivalent to a map from $V \times V \rightarrow W$, but this is not how I'll use it). Call it $L_\alpha$ for brevity.

What is $dG_{F(\alpha)}$? Again, for each $\alpha \in A$, it's a linear map from $W \rightarrow X$. So really $dG_{F(-)}: A \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(W,X)$. Its derivative at $\alpha$ is a linear map from $V \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(W,X)$. Call it $M_\alpha$ for brevity.

What is the composition $dG_{F(\alpha)} \circ dF_{\alpha}$? For each $\alpha \in A$, it's a linear map from $V \rightarrow X$. So really $dG_{F(-)}\circ dF_-: A \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(V,X)$. Its derivative at $\alpha$ is a linear map from $V \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(V,X)$. Call it $N_\alpha$ for brevity.

*Claim*: $N_\alpha(v) = M_\alpha(v) \circ dF_\alpha + dG_{F(\alpha)} \circ L_\alpha(v)$.

Note that each of the $\circ$ "products" is $\operatorname{Hom}(W,X) \times \operatorname{Hom}(V,W) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(V,X)$, i.e. simply a composition of linear maps, which in coordinates is a matrix product, and, as the Claim shows, acts as a product here.

*Sketch of Proof*: The defining property of $L_\alpha$ is that $dF_v = dF_\alpha + L_\alpha(v-\alpha) + o(\|v-\alpha\|)$. The defining property of $M_\alpha$ is similar. If we compose these we get $dG_{F(v)}\circ dF_v = dG_{F(\alpha)}\circ dF_\alpha + dG_{F(\alpha)} \circ L_\alpha(v-\alpha) + M_\alpha(v-\alpha) \circ dF_\alpha + o(\|v-\alpha\|)$, because the term $M_\alpha(F(v)-F(\alpha))\circ L_\alpha(v-\alpha)$ is approximately quadratic in $v-\alpha$, and thus is $o(\|v-\alpha\|)$. This is exactly the defining property for the derivative of $dG_{F(-)}\circ dF_-$, so this proves that the derivative $N_\alpha$ is as stated.

In case you haven't seen [little-$o$ notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation), the $o(\|v-\alpha\|)$ just refers to terms which are lower order than $v-\alpha$ as $v \rightarrow \alpha$ (e.g. quadratic is lower order than linear for small inputs). See the link for a formal definition.

In some single variable textbooks, the same technique is used for proving the product rule. It's really the same thing that's going on here.

---

*Here's an explanation of the chain rule part of this*:

Now $L_\alpha$ is simply the second derivative of $F$, call it $d^2F_\alpha$. To compute $M_\alpha$ in terms of derivatives of $F$ and $G$, use the chain rule. We have $F: A \rightarrow W$ and $dG_-: W \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(W,X)$, and $dG_{F(-)}$ is the composition of these maps (instead of the product; see above and compare the difference). The derivative of $F$ at $\alpha$ is $dF_\alpha: V \rightarrow W$ and the derivative of $dG_-$ at $F(\alpha)$ is $d^2G_{F(\alpha)}: W \rightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(W,X)$. So $M_\alpha$ is $d^2G_{F(\alpha)} \circ dF_\alpha : V \rightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(W,X)$.

---

*Overall answer for the second derivative of a composition*:

So overall $d^2(G\circ F)_\alpha(v) = (d^2G_{F(\alpha)} \circ dF_\alpha)(v) \circ dF_\alpha + dG_{F(\alpha)} \circ d^2F_\alpha(v)$, with each side of this equation an element of $\operatorname{Hom}(V,X)$.

---

*Comparison with single variable*:

In single variable if we have $f$ and $g$ twice-differentiable real-valued maps on $\mathbb{R}$ and a composition $g\circ f$, then we have $(g\circ f)'(x) = g'(f(x)) f'(x)$ and $(g\circ f)''(x) = g''(f(x))f'(x)^2 + g'(f(x))f''(x)$. Notice that this matches the formula above, with $x$ in place of $\alpha$. (There's no mention of $v$ because this is suppressed in single variable calculus and the derivative is simply reported as a scalar, corresponding to either [take your pick; they're equivalent] a the linear map given by multiplication by that scalar, or in coordinates to a $1\times 1$ matrix with that entry, or in coordinates to a single element vector after plugging in the vector $[1]$.)